# Terraform error when trying to use "for_each"

Tags: foreach, terraform

Using hashicorp/aws v5.40.0 and Terraform >= 1.7.4

I'm still a newbie trying to expand how to use Terraform using more of a dynamic deployment.  In this case, deploying using subnet counts.

Using var.subnetcount to create public subnets as follows:

```
`resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = var.subnet_count # in order to use the count index, we need to           declare that we are using the answer to the question about how many subnets are to be created
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.my-vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.1.${count.index}.0/24"
}`
```

And I'm trying to put a resource in each subnet as follows:

```
`resource "aws_instance" "EC2" {
  ami                    = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux.id
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  key_name               = var.key
  for_each               = toset(data.aws_subnets.public.ids)
  subnet_id              = "each.value.id"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh.id]
}`
```

But I'm getting the following error when trying to apply
`│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'each.value.id' does not exist │   status code: 400, request id: c6cd6da1-1ce2-4502-b9ac-3f49b45c93bc │  │   with aws_instance.EC2["**subnet-04b3859df1d5ea4ca"**], │   on Test_EC2.tf line 12, in resource "aws_instance" "EC2": │   12: resource "aws_instance" "EC2" {`

I was expecting an EC2 instance to be created per subnet and that using the "for_each" subnet ID would work.

I hope there is a better method?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be happening because you're adding `.id` to `each.value` which isn't needed. You can simply use `each.value` directly in your `aws_instance` resource like this:

```
subnet_id = each.value
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the following error:

Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on Test_EC2.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "EC2":
│   16:   for_each               = toset(data.aws_subnets.public.ids)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_subnets.public.ids is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that
│ cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full
│ set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **literal string** `"each.value.id"`. It should be without quotes and no `id`:

```
subnet_id              = each.value
```